# Pandas creating a new variable based on two existing variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code I think is highly inefficient. Is there a better way to do this type common recoding in pandas?

```
df['F'] = 0
df['F'][(df['B'] >=3) & (df['C'] >=4.35)] = 1
df['F'][(df['B'] >=3) & (df['C'] < 4.35)] = 2
df['F'][(df['B'] < 3) & (df['C'] >=4.35)] = 3
df['F'][(df['B'] < 3) & (df['C'] < 4.35)] = 4
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and cache boolean masks to variables for better performance:

```
m1 = df['B'] >= 3
m2 = df['C'] >= 4.35
m3 = df['C'] < 4.35
m4 = df['B'] < 3

df['F'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & m3, m4 & m2, m4 & m3], [1,2,3,4], default=0)
```

Comment: Good one! I like it

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, you can make use of the fact that booleans are actually integers (False == 0, True == 1) and use simple arithmetic:

```
df['F'] = 1 + (df['C'] < 4.35) + 2 * (df['B'] < 3)
```

Note that this will ignore any NaN's in your `B` and `C` columns, these will be assigned as being above your limit.

Comment: clever. thanks for the solution. I am looking for a generic solution because we do this type of data processing all the time. sometimes it may not be mathematically aligned as 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: This answer is in some sense more general, because it is easier to add more columns (by using `4 *`, `8 *`, etc...) without having to write out all combinations of masks (which grows exponentially).